# Is retrying a failed write consistent with at most once delivery?

Tags: netty

We want to implement at most once delivery of messages, while also retrying as many failure cases as possible.  Is retrying a failed write consistent with at most once delivery?

To do this we add an `operationComplete` listener to the channel promise of a `write`, and retry the operation when the promise returns false for `isSuccess`.  In this case, is the message guaranteed NOT to have been delivered when the promise returns completes with `isSuccess` false?

We are using TCP.

Answer (score 1):

All of this depends a bit on the `transport` (like is it TCP / UDP etc) but generally speaking yes. If a `ChannelFuture` is failed it means the operations was not successful and so you may be able to retry. If you can retry or not depends again on the semantics of the protocol.